# How to convert a string that includes decimal point to a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, calculator, decimal-point

The input string is like this

`a=(2.5+6/3.7*2.09)`

It needs to be converted to a list to be used as a calculator

`b=['2.5','+','6','/','3.7','*','2.09']`

How to convert the string a to a list like b, such that the decimal point numbers are considered as a single number not like `['2','.','0','9']`

Comment: Try writing Regex

Comment: In any specific language?

Comment: You need a _parser_ for this most likely.  A pure regex solution may not be enough.

Comment: @siserte python

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: B is the o/p you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use split a string by Multiple Delimiters :

```
import re
a="2.5+6/3.7*2.09"
print(re.split('\+|\*|/',a))
```

output:

```
['2.5', '6', '3.7', '2.09']
```

Full solution:

```
import re
a="2.5+6/3.7*2.09"
pattern='\+|\/+|\*'
strings=re.split('\+|\*|/',a)
sym=re.findall(pattern,a)
new=[]
for i in range(len(strings)):
    new.append(strings[i])
    try:
        new.append(sym[i])
    except IndexError:
        pass
print(new)
```

output:

```
['2.5', '+', '6', '/', '3.7', '*', '2.09']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get your result

```
result = []
counter = 0
len_a = len(a)
symbol_list = ['*','(',')','+','-','/']

while counter < len_a:
    helper = ''
    if a[counter] not in symbol_list:
        helper += a[counter]
    else:
        result.append(helper)
        result.append(a[counter])
        helper = ''
    counter += 1
return result
```